# how to create "between" condition with lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

i have search code with some paramethers now i want impeliment between to number(check `exchangeNo` and `exchangeNo2` in `MinutesNo`  ) and `MinutesNo` in data base is string field same as `exchangeNo & exchangeNo2` that's my code:

```
where stationsID.Contains(station.ID) &&
      ((exchangeNo == null || exchaminut.MinutesNo.CompareTo(exchangeNo)>=0) &&
       (exchangeNo2 == null || exchaminut.MinutesNo.CompareTo(exchangeNo2)<0))&&...
```

that's not wroking correctly. what i have to do?

Comment: any answer for this question?

Comment: What does the data you are querying look like? What result do you get from your query above and what is the expected result you are looking for?

Comment: The code should work.  So I suspect the string comparison is not sorting the way you expect is to work.  I would use an OrderBy to get an better understanding of what is actually being returned.

Comment: @Hypnobrew my data are numbes, my result  get from my query is not true and i want impeliment between tow numbers

Comment: @jdweng no that's not wrok correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was type of field in database that string cannot compare, i change it to bigint and worked